# Navigation Bar appears under a large status bar when using TabBarController

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitabbarcontroller, uinavigationbar

When I added a TabBarController, the navigation bar of TestController appears under a large status bar (see screenshot).  Am I missing a setting somewhere? Thanks.

[image]

Comment: show some code please. how did you go about adding the navcontroller and the tabbarcontroller

Comment: Is `TestController`  subclass of UINavigationController ?Or you just add a NavigationBar?

Answer (score 0):

```
Here it is not clear what do you want to do with navigation bar.If you want to just hide navigation bar,then hide it when you add navigation bar to tab bar controller or you can hide it seperately in each view controller.

 UINavigationController *nav1=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:vcPictureListing];
    nav1.navigationBarHidden=TRUE;

or for doing it in each viewcontroller you can do it like
 self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden=TRUE;

This is just for hiding default one.If you want any navigation bar to be present then you can hide this default one and add imageview and button at top of viewcontroller and can have custom one
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have added an image for naviagationbar then check you have not added shadow image for navigationbar. Check shadow image propery of navigationbar.